# MySQL по умолчанию выбирает первое значение

Tags: php, mysql

Привет! Сделал выбору всех пользователей из базы, но он выбирает только первое значение таблицы users, в запросе условий никаких нет.
Проблема в том, что выводит самую первую запись в таблице, но если добавить какое-либо условие, то выбирает и остальные. Код запроса:

```
function show_users()
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    return $this->db->fetch_array($q);
}
```

А потом `var_dump($user->show_users());`

Comment: Хотя когда считаю кол-во юзеров, выводит точную цифру.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используешь это: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

То:

mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Выбирает **одну строку** из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный массив

Попробуй fetch_all: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: @mayar видимо оно и используется, т.к коннект по умолчанию - mysqli_connect.

Как исправить не подскажите? :)

Comment: fetch_all: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Ну, или в цикле строчки перебирать...

Comment: @mayar спасибо, помогло.